# overriding transition property from

Tags: css, css-animations, transition

I'm wondering if there is any way to override just the transition-property that I define with the following statement:

```
transition: all 0.2s;
```

I would like to override transition-property to:

```
transition-property: width, height, opacity, font-size;
```

However, when I add the second line after the first, transition won't work. Why is that?

The reason why I'm trying to do that is because my transition won't work on Safari 5.1 if I define it with all, so I want to override property all with individual properties just for the webkit support.

Answer (score 1):

you could also use just one property

```css
div {
    transition: width 2s, height 2s, font-size 2s,opacity 2s;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    opacity: 1;
    font-size: 20px;
    background-color: red;
}

div:hover {
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
    opacity: 0.8;
    font-size: 40px;
        background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div>Hello</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if(Object.prototype.toString.call(window.HTMLElement).indexOf('Constructor') > 0){

var div = document.getElementById("idName");
div.style.transition-property = "width:value,height:value,opacity:value, font-size:value;";

}
```

**Use this in javascript function to check if the browser is Safari and set the style to that particular element**

Answer (score 0):

It works for me

```css
div {
    transition: all 2s;
    transition-property: width, height, opacity, font-size;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    opacity: 1;
    font-size: 20px;
    background-color: red;
}

div:hover {
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
    opacity: 0.8;
    font-size: 40px;
        background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div>Hello</div>
```